# QString - UTF8 embedded in 16Bits?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm very surprised. I started to dig into `QString::data()` while trying to help another asker here with a QString vs. ASCII related problem.

I made the following piece of code which looks at every 16bit packs of the QString data and found, that letters like 'ä' and 'ß' seem to be encoded in UTF-8 but use 16 bits to store the 8 bits. Of course they can do as they like but the docs say QString would be in UTF-16. But it looks different to me.

**Correction:
The QString doc of Qt 4.8 don't really mention UTF-16.
But it also doesn't state that UTF-8 is used with 16bits.**

Please, can someone enlighten me !?

My code:

```
QString h("AßB");

char * pt = (char*)h.data();

for(int i = 0; ;i+=2) {

   // get 16bit value
   u_int16_t s = *(u_int16_t*)(pt + i);

   // break condition
   if(s == 0) break;

   qDebug() << i << s << QChar(s) << h.size();
}
```

And what qDebug() tells me:

```
0 65 'A' 4 
2 195 'Ã' 4 
4 159 '' 4 
6 66 'B' 4
```

Note, that the 'ß' seems to be UTF-8 encoded while still using 16bit for both parts of the encoding.

195 159 is the UTF-8 encoding of 'ß'.

My char map tells me the UTF-16 representation should be 0x00DF for 'ß'. And that's what I hoped to get.

Also note that `QString::size()` reports the questionable size of 4 instead of 3.

Comment: which OS and Qt version are you using?

Comment: @Meefte Qt 4.8 and Debian 8 (Jessie). Do you get other results ?

Comment: I got `0 65 'A' 3 | 2 223 '00\u00df' 3 | 4 66 'B' 3` on Windows 7 and Qt 5.5

Comment: @Meefte That's what I expected to see .. Hm .. maybe Qt versions below 5 use a special format. Actuall I rechecked the doc of my version and it states only following: `QString stores a string of 16-bit QChars, where each QChar corresponds one Unicode 4.0 character. (Unicode characters with code values above 65535 are stored using surrogate pairs, i.e., two consecutive QChars.)` How does this fit with my result above ? Seems bit weird to me.

Comment: Non-ASCII characters in string literals are not portable. Don't assume they will work as you expect in your system. In particular, your system may use UTF-8 for source encoding, but Qt uses `fromAscii` in its constructor.

Comment: To avoid the source file encoding issues n.m. mentioned, try with `QString h = QString::fromLatin1("A\337B")` which avoids non-ascii literals and does an explicit conversion from latin1 to QString.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thanks for the hint. Now, the output is as expected for the characters above: `0 65 'A' 3, 2 223 'ß' 3, 4 66 'B' 3`. I'll experiment a bit more with this.

Answer (score 0):

QString data is stored internally as Unicode.  From the qt docs:

```
QString str = "Hello";
```

"QString converts the const char * data into Unicode using the fromUtf8() function."

Here's the link: [QString Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details)

Strangely, I don't see any toUTF16() method; although it does have a toUTF8 one.

Also, UTF-16 is not Unicode:

"The Unicode Standard encodes characters in the range U+0000..U+10FFFF, which amounts to a 21-bit code space. Depending on the encoding form you choose (UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32), each character will then be represented either as a sequence of one to four 8-bit bytes, one or two 16-bit code units, or a single 32-bit code unit."

From: [Frequently Asked Questions - UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)

Edit:

I do know that MSVC used to be used to compile both Unicode and non-Unicode builds.  From M$:

"Unicode UTF-16 encoding

Represents Unicode characters as sequences of 16-bit integers. Your application can use the UnicodeEncoding class to convert characters to and from UTF-16 encoding.

UTF-16 is often used natively, as in the Microsoft.Net char type, the Windows WCHAR type, and other common types. Most common Unicode code points take only one UTF-16 code point (2 bytes). Unicode supplementary characters U+10000 and greater still require two UTF-16 surrogate code points."

Found on [.NET Framework 3.5 - Using Unicode Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs0350fy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Thus, M$ IS often using UTF-16 internally.  Unicode is the 21-bit long list of symbols, and there are various UTF formats to encode them.

How does this affect you on Ubuntu?  M$ is encoding things internally in UTF-16 and calling them Unicode.

Frank Osterfeld evidently found the problem in your code: that the compiler was using the source file's encoding to make a string literal.  It is bizarre that it is using a 16-bit encoding, and coming up with the UTF-8 value; thereby coming up with the wrong character sequence!  I wonder if it would as "A" with an umlaut over it, if you printed out the QString.  It may be that it gets converted back to the same UTF-8 before you ever see it, although the compiler evidently doesn't understand it.  Frank and you, have been able to prove that on Ubuntu, Qt uses UTF-16.  It seems that one hardly ever sees Unicode characters in computer data when not encoded (i.e. 21-bits).  "Unicode" builds are evidently UTF-16 builds.

Comment: What do you mean with "Also, UTF-16 is not Unicode"?

Comment: As per the quote, Unicode is 21 bits.  UTF-16 is 16.  As to whether Qt is using all 21 bits or just 16, I can't say for sure.  This may explain Aaron's strange results.

Comment: Unicode is not any bits. It just assigns numbers to characters. UTF-16 defines an encoding for those numbers in 16-bit code units. it does take at least 21 bits to represent all of Unicode, however, and UTF-16 allows one or two code units (2 or 4 bytes) to encode a single Unicode code point.

Comment: I personally found this [talk](https://youtu.be/n0GK-9f4dl8) very interesting, but just looking at the [specs](http://www.unicode.org/standard/principles.html), you'll find that UTF-16 is one of the Unicode encoding forms (the worst IMHO, but still part of the standard).

Comment: I wondered if that might be the case.  I suppose there would have been less confusion, however, if they had simply called them UTF-16 builds instead of Unicode builds.  I already knew that Qt stored it internally as Unicode already, but I didn't know it was UTF-16, at least in Linux, and evidently on WIndows.  Past knowing it was stored as Unicode internally, I was finding out myself along with you guys.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that I (the questioner) used Qt4.8 when I asked the question. Qt4 uses 16bits to store a string but not UTF16.

Comment: Interesting.  What is the 16-bit Unicode encoding that is not UTF-16?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be unicode then. The docs just say it's 16bits. utf16 is not mentioned in the Qt4.8 QString docs.

Comment: I think Frank Osterfelds and n.m.s comments above solved the mystery.

Comment: From the 4.8 docs: "QString stores a string of 16-bit QChars, where each QChar corresponds one Unicode 4.0 character. (Unicode characters with code values above 65535 are stored using surrogate pairs, i.e., two consecutive QChars.)"  It is indeed Unicode.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html